# WebDriver with GeckoDriver - Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I use Firefox 91.0 and GeckoDriver 0.29.1. Firefox is executed when script is running, but an empty page is opened.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"));
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(binary);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.hu");
```

I got following error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds
> for Firefox to start. Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision:
> 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: Maybe you need to update your geckodrive search for one computable with your Firefox version

Comment: @JS_INF : It is supported: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html